# How to use FTP to connect to Azure scale set Instance

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, load-balancing, azure-vm-scale-set

So i have created a scale set in Azure (2 windows server 2016 VMs). I want to have a PHP application running on them. I want to know if it is possible to use an FTP connection to remotely upload/edit my php files which are going to be on the VMs. If not, what are the others ways i can use to remotely edit/upload my php files?.
 This is my first time working with a scaleset.
 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to use FTP in php:

```
//open a connection
$conn = ftp_connect($host);

//login to server
ftp_login($conn, $user, $pass);

//upload file
if (ftp_put($conn, $remoteFile, $localFile, FTP_ASCII)) {
    return "<p>successfully uploaded $localFile to $remoteFile</p>";
} else {
    return "<p>There was a problem while uploading $remoteFile</p>";
}
```

See the manual for more FTP functions http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php